# Update single entry in GLSL array

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I have an array in my vertex shader like this:

```
uniform mat4 MeshTransforms[20];
```

At the moment I'm just updating the entire array of matrices like so:

```
int meshTransforms = ARBShaderObjects.glGetUniformLocationARB(shader, "MeshTransforms");
ARBShaderObjects.glUniformMatrix4ARB(meshTransforms, false, UnitTransformMatrices);
```

Where `UnitTransformMatrices` is a float buffer containing the transform matrices of some units.

I'd like to just update a single matrix in the array (just update one unit transform matrix). So how can I overwrite a single matrix in the middle of the matrix array?

This is using the LWJGL, so I'm limited to the functionality it provides.

Comment: Can't you use the put method? UnitTransformMatrices.put(at, num)

Comment: Thanks Luis, but that would only update the copy sitting in RAM, not what's on the video card's memory.

Comment: Please stop using the ARBShaderObjects extension. GLSL has been core OpenGL for 8+ years now; just use the core feature.

Comment: Thanks Nicol, do you know how to do that in LWJGL and would that help me with the question I have?

Comment: Shaders became standard in GL 2.0, so you should find the appropriate functions in the `GL20` class. And no, it doesn't have anything to do with your problem specifically, but you still shouldn't use the old extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`glGetUniformLocation`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetUniformLocation). In the description section, the element operator '[]' may be used to select elements within arrays. So you would grab the location

```
GLuint location = glGetUniformLocation( vertexShader , "variable[element]" );
```

Then from [`glUniform`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glUniform).

```
glvoid glUniformMatrix4fv( location , count , bool Transpose ,  const GLfloat *value);
```

Location is from above, count is the number of elements you plan on changing( sequentially from "location") and the rest you know.

I am not aware of the limitations you have in place with LWJGL, but am only hoping to set you on the right track to show you what's possible so you can check out your own documentation.